# Why do local notifications show up even when the application is in foreground?

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm working on the notifications side of a game and I have a problem with the way iOS handles local notifications.

In the documentation of the delegate `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` it states the following:

`If the application is running in the foreground, there is no alert, badging, or sound; instead, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: method is called if the delegate implements it.`

However, when a local notification is supposed to pop up and my application is running on the foreground it will first fire that delegate (it's empty) and then show the alert anyway.

I'd like to know of a way to exclusively handle local notifications when the application is running in the foreground. Is that even possible?

Short example why I need this: When a player starts a building a local notification is created to alert him when the building is finished (up to 6 hours). If however, the user is in the game when this notification is supposed to pop up I'd like to not show it since he can already see the building is finished.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you don't do something like show an alertview in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification`?

Comment: Currently the delegate is completely empty but I will try to remove that notification in the delegate and maybe it won't show up further.

Answer (score 3):

```
application:didReceiveLocalNotification:
```

you need to handle whether you want to show the notification as an alert or badge or a sound. So when your app is in the background, the pop up alert/badge/sound will notify the user about the message(in your case that the building is complete). But you can choose to ignore this in the delegate method.

EDIT:
Once the method is fired and your application is active, you can discard the notification

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:myNotification];
```

**Your assumption that it will pop up when in foreground is wrong.**

Comment: It is not an assumption. It actually does pop up when in foreground after going trough the delegate. I even tried canceling the notification in that delegate and it will still show up after getting out of it.

Comment: That's exactly what I tried and the notification still shows up.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `cancelAllLocalNotifications:` it dismisses currently displayed alerts even if the notification has already fired.

Comment: Yeah but then I'd cancel other notifications that might be needed further. I could however cancel only that one. I will check it and tell you if it works.